# pie chart shiny application using selectinput

Tags: r

when i execute my code i have only the the siderbarPanel in my application,and when i choose the state nothing to show .
the probleme that i don't have any error in my code to correct in

My data :

```
total.death=c(48, 24, 12, 22)
total.recovred=c(12, 22, 78, 21)
total.cases=c(553, 226, 742, 370)
State=c ('USA', 'Belgium', 'France','Russia')
df2 = data.frame(State,total.cases,total.recovered,total.death)
```

My code:

```
library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)
ui=fluidPage(

  selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
              choices = df2$State, 
              selected = 1),

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value"))),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text1"),

    plotOutput("mypie")

  ))


s=function(input, output) {

  output$text1 <- renderText({ 
    txt = as.character(input$select)
    paste("text is", txt)

  })
  output$mypie <- renderPlot(

    {labels=c("unrecovered","recovered","death")
    S=filter(df2,df2[1]==as.character(input$select) )
    S=c(S[2],S[3],S[4])

    plot_ly(labels = ~labels,
            values = ~S, type = 'pie',
            marker = list(colors = brewer.pal(7,"Spectral")))



    })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server = s)
```

Comment: I edit it, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `plotlyOutput` and `renderPlotly`. See below for working version. Minor modifications made to spelling, case-sensitive names, etc.

**Edit**: This includes `S = unlist(S[-1])` for plotting as mentioned in comments.

```
total.death=c(48, 24, 12, 22)
total.recovered=c(12, 22, 78, 21)
total.cases=c(553, 226, 742, 370)
State=c ('USA', 'Belgium', 'France','Russia')
df2 = data.frame(State,total.cases,total.recovered,total.death)

library(shiny)
library(plotly)
library(RColorBrewer)

ui=fluidPage(
  selectInput("select", label = h3("Select box"), 
              choices = df2$State, 
              selected = 1),

  hr(),
  fluidRow(column(3, verbatimTextOutput("value"))),
  mainPanel(
    textOutput("text1"),
    plotlyOutput("mypie")
  )
)

s=function(input, output) {

  output$text1 <- renderText({ 
    txt = as.character(input$select)
    paste("text is", txt)
  })

  output$mypie <- renderPlotly({
    labels=c("unrecovered","recovered","death")
    S=filter(df2, df2$State==as.character(input$select))

    S = unlist(S[-1])

    plot_ly(labels = ~labels,
            values = ~S, type = 'pie',
            marker = list(colors = brewer.pal(7,"Spectral")))
  })

}

shinyApp(ui=ui,server = s)
```

Comment: i tried with plotlyOutput but in vain,plz see the code i edit it

Comment: now it show me the the pie chart, but in Rviewer,not in my applicartion shiny

Comment: i just add S = unlist(S[-1])

Comment: output$mypie <- renderPlot(
    
    {labels=c("unrecovered","recovered","death")
    S=filter(df2,df2[1]==as.character(input$select) )
    S=unlist(S[-1])
   
    
    plot_ly(labels = ~labels,
            values = ~S, type = 'pie',
            marker = list(colors = brewer.pal(7,"Spectral")))
    
    
    
    })

Comment: i delet S=c(S[1],S[2],S[3]) but i have same problem

Comment: you still have `renderPlot` _not_ `renderPlotly` (notice the "ly") - also make sure you use `plotlyOutput` _not_ `plotOutput`